# SlideTabs for Wordpress autoheight

Tags: javascript, wordpress

IF anyone is familiar with slidetbas for wordpress can you please help me out.

It there a way to autoheight the content viewer based on the active tab?

I tried to add something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#slidetabs_983").setContentHeight();
});
```

to the javascript for my particular slidetab (ID 983) but that didn't work.

http://www.slidetabs.com/ is their website and you can see a demo on there.

thanks

Comment: use autoHeight: true to slider tab setting

Comment: thanks, didn't see that option :)

Comment: If it solves your problem, please approve the answer

Comment: @TamilSelvan You need to answer it, and not simply comment then? I'm new.

Answer (score 0):

use `autoHeight: true` to slider tab setting

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#slidetabs_983").slidetabs({
        // Define any options below
        autoHeight: true
    });
});
```